# pandas converting datetimeindex to timedeltaindex

Tags: pandas

I have two dfs. One has a DatetimeIndex, the other one a TimedeltaIndex.

```
DatetimeIndex(['2017-12-11 09:00:00', '2017-12-11 09:01:00',
           ...
           '2017-12-11 14:59:00', '2017-12-11 15:00:00'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=361, freq='T')


TimedeltaIndex(['09:00:00', '09:01:00', '09:02:00', '09:03:00', '09:04:00',
            ...
            '14:55:00', '14:56:00', '14:57:00', '14:58:00', '14:59:00'],
           dtype='timedelta64[ns]', name='ts', length=300, freq=None)
```

I am trying to concatenate them

```
pd.concat([d1, d2], axis=1)
```

but it throws

```
'Index' object has no attribute 'freq'
```

presumably because of the different index times. I tried to change the index by using d1.index.appy or to_timedelta but this fails as I cant use apply on an index and and using pd.to_timedelta throws

```
Argument 'values' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got Index)
```

There must be some straightforward way I am missing. Any suggestions how I could do that easily. I don't require the date information, so any solution may drop this.

Comment: Some [mcve], along with expected output would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) with [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetmeIndex.strftime.html):

```
d1.index = pd.to_timedelta(d1.index.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

Or:

```
d1 = d1.set_index(pd.to_timedelta(d1.index.strftime('%H:%M:%S')))
```